# how to get phase fft of a signal &-- can i get phase in time domain?

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals, signal-processing, fft

i can get magnitude of signal coming from .wav file , but how to get the phase of that signal too ,,, 
Here is the where i browse for .wav file and extract the signal

```
def browse_wav(self):

    filepath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Single File', "C:\Users\Hanna Nabil\Documents",'*.wav')
    f= str(filepath)
    if f != "":
        spf = wave.open(f, 'r')
    import contextlib

    with contextlib.closing(wave.open(f, 'r')) as f:
        frames = f.getnframes()
        rate = f.getframerate()
        duration = frames / float(rate)
        print "Duration is " , duration

    # Extract Raw Audio from Wav File
    self.signal = spf.readframes(-1)
    self.signal = np.fromstring(self.signal, 'Int16')
    self.fs = spf.getframerate()
    print "Sampling Rate is " ,self.fs

    # If Stereo
    if spf.getnchannels() == 2:
        print 'Just mono files'
        sys.exit(0)

    #self.time = np.linspace(0, len(self.signal) / fs, num=len(self.signal))
    self.time = np.linspace(0, duration, self.fs * duration)

    self.xfourier = fftfreq(self.signal.size, d=self.time[1] - self.time[0])
    self.yfourier = np.abs(fft(self.signal))  # signal magnitude

    self.zico = self.yfourier
    self.cut_signal = ifft(self.zico)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The complex spectrum contains both the magnitude and phase. You get the magnitude by calculating the absolute value and you get the phase by calculating the angle. You can use [`numpy.angle()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.angle.html) to get the phase:

```
spectrum = fft(self.signal)
magnitude = np.abs(spectrum)
phase = np.angle(spectrum)
```

Answer (score -1):

For the answer from Lukas Lalinsky I find I have to add pi/2 for some reason to get the correct answer.

Also for points:

```
N = len(t)
Amplitude = 2/N *  np.abs(magnitude)
```

Comment: You shouldn’t add pi/2. This likely stems from a misconception.